# Accessing an ObjC object from a C function callback

Tags: objective-c, c, callback

I'm playing around a bit with global hot keys in Carbon, and I registered a hot key. When the hot key is pressed, this function is called:

```
OSStatus myHotKeyHandler(EventHandlerCallRef nextHandler, EventRef anEvent, void *userData) {
    ...
}
```

This function is in the same file as my app delegate's definition. How do I now call an ObjC method on my delegate in that function?

```
[self aMethod];
```

I cant add a `void*` (to be a pointer to my class instance) to the C function, because I am not the one calling it.

I tried to convert the method into a class method and then call it with `[AppDelegate aFunction]`, which works but then I cant use my instance variables!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Give the pointer to your class instance as parameter for `userData` when you register your event handler. You will then get this pointer back inside the handler as `userData`.

Answer (score 8):

You're reinventing the wheel.  Use a wrapper:

http://github.com/davedelong/DDHotKey

<sub>well perhaps not a *wheel*, since hot keys aren't "trivial" concepts.  maybe you're reinventing a differential? or something? ;)</sub>

Answer (score 3):

Example code

```
InstallApplicationEventHandler(&MyHotKeyHandler,1,&eventType,(void *)self,NULL);
...

OSStatus MyHotKeyHandler(EventHandlerCallRef nextHandler,EventRef theEvent,
                         void *userData)
{
    [(yourAppDelegate *)userData dosomething];
}
```