# Calling Objective-C method from C code

Tags: objective-c, c

I'm trying to call a method implemented in Obj-C from C code as follows:

// MainViewController.m

```
- (void)Test
{
    [self outputLine:@"Called from MyCode.c"];
}
.
.
.
cFunc(id param);
.
.
.
```

// MyCode.c

```
void cFunc(id param)
{
    [param Test]; // compilation error: Parse issue: Expected expression
}
```

I guess it happens since the MainViewController is not declared in MyCode.c, but when I #include the MainViewController.h I get tons of other errors that suggests I'm totally wrong...
How should I handle it correctly?

TIA

Comment: possible duplicate of [Call Objective-C function from C function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6219531/call-objective-c-function-from-c-function)

Comment: @OneManCrew: That question covers a different issue, despite its title. I've edited it to make the title match the subject. I would be surprised, however, if there wasn't a duplicate of this somewhere.

Comment: although it really sounds trivial, even for an Obj-C newbie like me I was quite surprised not to find a similar answer, but maybe it's just my searching skills...

Answer (score 4):

You should compile the `MyCode.c` file as Objective-C. Objective-C is a superset of C, but it's not true the other way around. You can't have Objective-C code interspersed with your "pure C" code if you are intending to compile it as C.

Answer (score 0):

Check: [using objc_msgSend to call a Objective C function with named arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2573805/using-objc-msgsend-to-call-a-objective-c-function-with-named-arguments)

```
void cFunc(id param) {
    objc_msgSend(param, sel_getUid("Test"));
}
```

But, as per the link above, this is dangerous for a few reasons, if your arguments don't fit in registers (i.e. floats, structs, blah blah).

The accepted way of doing this is to cast objc_msgSend:

```
void cFunc(id param) {
    // Now let's pretend that you want to send someFloat to your method

    void (*objc_msgSendTyped)(id self, SEL _cmd, float bar) = (void*)objc_msgSend;

    float someFloat = 42.f;
    objc_msgSendTyped(param, sel_getUid("Test"), someFloat);
}
```

Comment: Since you have no parameters this is an easy way to do it.  Just don't use this if you have to pass parameters to the message, check @Ken's answer to the question I linked to.

Comment: Never call objc_msgSend() without casting it to the correct function pointer type.

Comment: That is true... but in this case it is fairly trivial because the OP's function was void anyway.  I'll edit to reflect your suggestion though and to reemphasize the method in the link I listed.

Comment: +1 because now it's edited, showing the proper way, and anyways I don't like "it's impossible"-style answers in general, which now mine apparently is.

Answer (score 0):

Just change your myCode.c to myCode.m :P

Don't be afraid to put C code in an Objective-C file.