# can C function call objective-C class method?

Tags: ios, objective-c

```
id  object_pointer;

(obj init method)...
   object_pointer = self;

void some-c-function( void )
{
   // Calling a class method from this C function:
   [Some_Obj_C_Class     class_method];

   // or to calling an object method:
   [object_pointer    object_method];
}
```

I have to write my highest level code in C functions so that part can be eventually ported to an embedded system.  I'm using iPads to simulate the hardware that's not available yet.

Comment: Have you tried it? Do you get any error? Could you clarify this question?

Comment: If the C code is in a .m file then yes, your C function can call Objective-C code.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calling Objective-C method from C code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17595086/calling-objective-c-method-from-c-code)

Comment: Ramy:  Yes I tried.  And it works okay.  Sorry -- I should have done that before posting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A C function can most certainly call an Objective-C method. In fact, a C function can even *be* an Objective-C method. Talking about *how* that works gets into the Objective-C runtime, a slightly related topic. An Objective-C method with no arguments can be thought of like a C function with exactly two arguments: `self` and `_cmd`. At compile time, Objective-C method calls are translated into calls to one of the `objc_msgSend` functions, which takes a selector and an object, in addition to any method arguments.

One thing that may be confusing is that because `self` is a sort of hidden argument in most methods, it will be inaccessible from a standard C function, even if you have it defined inside the `@implementation` of your object. As long as you are using Objective-C variables that are accessible in the scope of your function, you can make Objective-C method calls.

Comment: It's easier than I thought.  iPads are a fantastic way to simulate new product hardware that doesn't exist yet.  I can demo the product on a table using a handful of iPads, everybody gets excited because they 'see' the product now, resulting in fruitful discussion.  I told them "The iPad is the 'face' of the product!"